# How do I run repeated measures ANOVA on files of different lengths in R?

Tags: r, anova

I ran a within-subjects study with 40 participants trying out all three conditions.

I have three output files per participant, one for each condition. The files contain the following columns: marker (which is irrelevant for ANOVA), error, timestamp.

The files are huge, and all different lengths since everyone took a different amount of time.

I don't know how to combine the files in a way that I can run ANOVA on them in R. I'm worried about the different file lengths.

I've been thinking about getting the mean error from each file and then running the ANOVA on that but I'm not sure it's legit.

Edit:

For context, result from reading one of the files:

[image]

The file sizes range from 714KB to 84107KB.

My three conditions are Spheres, Rubber Bands, Arrows.

Following @L Tyrone's advice I've used dput()

```
 First1ArrowsDance2 <-
  structure(
    list(
      markers = c(
        "Avatar Stopped",
        "Correct",
        "Correct",
        "Correct",
        "Correct",
        "Correct",
        "Correct",
        "Correct",
        "Correct",
        "Correct"
      ),
      error = c(
        0.2950831,
        0.2950782,
        0.2950698,
        0.295059,
        0.291691,
        0.2916831,
        0.2916784,
        0.2916738,
        0.2916692,
        0.2916639
      ),
      timestamp = c(
        48.28341,
        48.29302,
        48.30605,
        48.31171,
        48.3166,
        48.32151,
        48.32629,
        48.33191,
        48.33756,
        48.34245
      )
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,
                  10L),
    class = "data.frame"
  )

    First1SpheresDance3 <-
  structure(
    list(
      markers = c(
        "Avatar Stopped",
        "Correct",
        "Correct",
        "Correct",
        "Correct",
        "Correct",
        "Correct",
        "Correct",
        "Correct",
        "Correct"
      ),
      error = c(
        0.2382652,
        0.2382898,
        0.2382811,
        0.2382223,
        0.2382176,
        0.2382117,
        0.2382296,
        0.2382211,
        0.236873,
        0.2368683
      ),
      timestamp = c(
        40.74294,
        40.74847,
        40.7535,
        40.76012,
        40.77242,
        40.77939,
        40.78485,
        40.79016,
        40.80041,
        40.8057
      )
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,
                  10L),
    class = "data.frame"
  )

    Second2RubberBandsDance3 <-
  structure(
    list(
      markers = c(
        "Avatar Stopped",
        "Correct",
        "Correct",
        "Correct",
        "Correct",
        "Correct",
        "Correct",
        "Correct",
        "Correct",
        "Correct"
      ),
      error = c(
        0.4020498,
        0.4020442,
        0.4020512,
        0.4020622,
        0.402067,
        0.4020713,
        0.4027897,
        0.4027941,
        0.4027986,
        0.4028135
      ),
      timestamp = c(
        57.91049,
        57.92506,
        57.93127,
        57.9364,
        57.94205,
        57.94752,
        57.95326,
        57.96183,
        57.96772,
        57.97733
      )
    ),
    row.names = c(NA,
                  10L),
    class = "data.frame"
  )
```

Comment: Welcome to SO onemorecoder. Your question needs some supporting information. Please review [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/articles/76995406/how-to-write-a-good-r-question-with-a-reproducible-example) and update your question accordingly. You can run `dput()` on your data e.g. `dput(df)` and paste the result into your question. If your data are too large, you can make a smaller 'dummy' dataset the replicates your issue Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the welcome @LTyrone :) I've added that to my post now. I guess the main thing will be replicating the varying file lengths as I just used a 1:10 range for all three example subsets.

Answer (score 1):

for structuring the data for ANOVA, you need to conbime all the files.

keep the errors and timestamp columns if they are your variables, and create a new column of participant identifier and a new column as the condition identifier. If mean error is your dv, you can get the mean in each file first.The typical repeated ANOVA code is like:

```
aov= aov(dv ~ iv1 +iv2+... + Error(participant.id/(within-p_factor1+ factor2+...)), 
data, 
contrast = contr.sum)
```

`summary(aov)`

Without knowing the structure of your files, it is hard to give you any code for data processing.